# d3 axis tick alignment

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 bar chart with, and the axis tick marks are centered below the bars (as I would expect). In this case, I would actually like to left align the axis ticks and have the ticks under the left edge of the bar. Is that possible?[image]

EDIT: Javascript for constructing the axis

```
// note width is just the width of the chart
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0,width], .1); 
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
```

Comment: Do you actually need the ticks? You could set the size of the ticks to zero (`axis.tickSize(0);`) and just use the tick text underneath each bar in the chart.

Comment: I would actually like to show the ticks

Comment: Can you provide the JS for how you construct the x axis?

Comment: I have posted it. I have found a workaround where I actually have two x-axes, one that displays the ticks/labels and uses an explicit range instead of range bands, and a second x-axis to just show the x-axis lines that has the range bands. This seems to accomplish what I'm trying to do but seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 3):

here is an example of left aligning the ticks.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6186172

the idea is that after you create the ticks you collect them and aligne them:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", 6)
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a new scale?

```
var padding = .1;

var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, n])
  .range([0 + padding, WIDTH + padding]);
```

Where `n` is the number of bars in your histogram.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this should be adjusted when you add the axis to your graph.

Try (assuming your graph is called svg):

```
var bandSize = xScale.rangeBand();

svg.append("svg:g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(-" + bandSize + "," + h + ")")
 .call(xAxis)
 .selectAll("text")
   .style("text-anchor", "start")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + bandSize + ", 0)");
```

In my experiments, this shifts the ticks to the start of each band, and retains the text centered under each band.